# ext3 option on error doesn't work

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I have a redhat server 5.8 with ext3 on top of lvm, i noticed ext3 has setting "Errors behavior:          Continue" in the fs super block, from the man page of mount command i readed this

> errors=continue / errors=remount-ro / errors=panic
>
> Define  the  behaviour when an error is encountered.  (Either ignore errors and just mark the     file system erroneous and continue, or remount the file system read-only, or panic and halt the system.)  The default is set in  the filesystem  superblock,  and  can  be changed  using tune2fs(8).

my file system are mounted in this way

```
/dev/vg00/rootvol       /                       ext3    defaults        1 1
```

My question is, why my filesystem are remount in readonly when a problem happen?

Comment: Well... `The default is set in the filesystem superblock, and can be changed using tune2fs(8).` - Since you are using defaults, it would seem that the default for your filesystem has been set to remount read-only.  As the man page said.  Use tune2fs to examine and change as needed.

Comment: default is always to remount-ro, so in the case of fs errors writes do not corrupt it even more.

Comment: Reading from Redhat Docs, i found this "So, "continue" and "remount-ro" both will trigger filesystem to be remounted read-only", but in the kernel doc ./filesystems/ext3.txt:106:errors=continue              Keep going on a filesystem error.